# I want to insert multiple post values in multiple rows in

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple `$_POST` data in `phpmysql`.
This is  my array

```
$options = array();
$options[1] = $_POST['A'];
$options[2] = $_POST['B'];
$options[3] = $_POST['C'];
$options[4] = $_POST['D'];
```

I want each input to take one row in the same column.
Please, I don't want to use `implode`. Thank you.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking here. Can you show some code you have tried, it might add a little context to your question

Comment: You want to insert all array values into same single column?

Comment: What's wrong with implode, condition of your homework? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < sizeof($options)) {
  $value_of_arr_options = $options[$i];
  $sql = "
       INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3, col4)
       VALUES ($value_of_arr_options)
  ";
  EXECUTE YOUR QUERY;
  $i++;
}
```

this is just a method looping into array values to insert in same table columns.
hope it renders the idea.